# R: Get function name called with package::function as string in R

Tags: r

Say i have a package `pack` given with a function `foo` in its namespace. 
I want to pass the function as `pack::foo` to another function `giveArgumentFunctionName`

```
giveArgumentFunctionName <- function(func)
{
    ## Get name of function argument
    function.name <- someFunction(func)

    return (function.name)
}
```

so that the function outputs the passed function name, without the package name, as a string. Something similar to this

```
> test <- giveArgumentFunctionName(pack::foo)
> test
"foo"
```

Have checkout similar problems solved with `deparse(substitute(foo::bar))` and `match.call()`, but the former gave the variable name if the function was assigned to one and frustration took the over hand when investigating the latter solution. How could this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `substitute` could be your friend. From the docs:

> `substitute` returns the parse tree for the (unevaluated) expression `expr`

This allows you to access the (unevaluated) expression `pack::foo` inside your function.

The following produces your desired outcome:

```
giveArgumentFunctionName <- function(func) {
  function.name <- as.character(substitute(func))[[3]]
  return (function.name)
}

giveArgumentFunctionName(pack::foo)
# [1] "foo"
giveArgumentFunctionName(pack::bar)
# [1] "bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
doit <- function(.){
  s <- substitute(.)
  d <- sapply(s, deparse)
  if(d[[1]] %in% c(":::", "::")){
    if(length(d)>2) d[3]
  } else d
}
```

It will return the second component for cases like first::second and first:::second, and the deparsed argument (as character vector) in other cases.