# R use the name of function as a parameter in formals

Tags: r, parameters, classification

I am working with several classification algorithms from different libraries (for example):

```
library(ranger) #RandomForest
library(gbm) #Gradient Boosting
```

I need to use `formals` function to get all the arguments from all of them.

The following attempts works perfectly:

```
formals(gbm)
formals(gbm::gbm)
formals("gbm")
        
functionName="gbm"
formals(functionName)
```

What I need is to parametrize the name of the package as well as the name of the function, but it fails. Something like this:

```
> packageName="gbm"
> functionName="gbm"
> formals(packageName::functionName)
Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘packageName’
```

Is there anyway to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Can [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904272/r-get-function-name-called-with-packagefunction-as-string-in-r)  be of help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good thing is that `::` accepts strings:

```r
`::`("gbm", "gbm")
```

The above code is working.

However, when we use an object name in which the string is stored, `::` takes this as literal expression and looks for a package called `packageName`.

```r
packageName <- functionName <- "gbm"
`::`(packageName, functionName)
#> Error in loadNamespace(x): there is no package called 'packageName'
```

With base R we can use `eval(bquote())` and evaluate the strings early with `.()`.

By evaluating the strings early with `.()` we make it clear that we are really looking for the string value (that is the value of `packageName`)  and not the object name itself.

```r
formals(eval(bquote(`::`(.(packageName), .(functionName)))))

#> $formula
#> formula(data)
#> 
#> $distribution
#> [1] "bernoulli"
#> 
#> $data
#> list()
#> 
#> $weights
#> 
#> 
#> $var.monotone
#> NULL
#> 
#> $n.trees
#> [1] 100
#> 
#> $interaction.depth
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $n.minobsinnode
#> [1] 10
#> 
#> $shrinkage
#> [1] 0.1
#> 
#> $bag.fraction
#> [1] 0.5
#> 
#> $train.fraction
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $cv.folds
#> [1] 0
#> 
#> $keep.data
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> $verbose
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> $class.stratify.cv
#> NULL
#> 
#> $n.cores
#> NULL
```

With {rlang} we can use `inject()` and `!! sym()`:

```r
library(rlang)
formals(inject(`::`(!! sym(packageName), !! sym(functionName))))
```

Of course in base R we always have the option to `eval(parse())`:

```r
packageName="gbm"
functionName="gbm"

formals(eval(str2lang(paste0(packageName, "::", functionName))))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>